# In django File upload option not show on page but other fields of form are shown

Tags: python, django, forms, image, file-upload

I want to create a form with image upload option.I created database with 4 fields:

- Artist
- Title
- geneder
- and 4th field is for image upload

first 3 fields are showing on web page but the image upload field is missing but at the same time upload field is showing in admin area and display image on webpage which i uploaded from admin area.

What can i do to show upload option in web page ?
Here is my complete code:

**Models.py**

```
class album(models.Model):
artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
album_logo = models.FileField()
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Form template page where only text fields are shown**

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: post your form.

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% include 'myapp/form-template.html' %}
                            <di class="form-group" class="col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-btn-primary">Submit</button>

Comment: mot this, the form of django and post it in the question

Comment: bro show the form, not the html, the form you have declared in forms.py or somewhere, and also post the view function for the image upload\

Answer (score 0):

Form is handling with 2 files:

**main file:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}
{% include 'myapp/form-template.html' %}
<di class="form-group" class="col-sm-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn-btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**Include file (form-template.html)**

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

In output of this form i get only text fields and image upload field is missing.
how can render upload field in output ?

Comment: anyone help me ?